# Copy current line to clipboard under cursor without mouse selection

Tags: vi, clipboard

How can i copy the current line under cursor in vi to the system clipboard?

I may paste the contents anywhere, in vi itself, or in shell, or in libreoffice app... And i am looking for simpler shortcuts like, one does `dd` to delete the line.

Comment: `yy` will copy the current line to the clipboard, but I do not think it will copy it to the system clipboard to be used elsewhere.

Comment: @Madhavan Kumar: What is your distro?

Comment: What do you mean simpler? Do you mean `dd` is simple so?

Comment: With Vim, provided that it's compiled with the right options, and provided that you're running it in an environment that support this: `"*yy`.

Comment: @MohammadEtemaddar, ubuntu 14.04 is my distro... yes, i see `dd` as easy to use as i don't need to move my fingers much when i am using this... basically, i am looking for copy command, and then paste it via `ctrl + shift + v` and not `p`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your Vim is compiled with the [`+clipboard` feature](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#+clipboard) (check if `+clipboard` appears in `:version` or in `vim --version`), then there are two special [registers](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#registers) that designate the system [clipboard](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/gui.html#clipboard). The register `"+` designates the clipboard, which is used by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. The register `"*` designates the primary selection, which is used by mouse selection and middle-click to paste.

To make a deletion, yank or put command act on an alternate register, prefix it with a double quote and the register character. For example, to copy the current line to the clipboard, type `"+yy`

If your Vim doesn't have the `+clipboard` feature, you can use an external utility to access the clipboard. You'll need Vim to have access to the X display, of course (the `DISPLAY` environment variable must be set). Use the [`:w` command](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#:w) with an argument starting with `!` to pipe the specified lines through a program. With [xsel](http://www.vergenet.net/~conrad/software/xsel/):

```
:.w !xsel -b
```

Comment: thanks a lot, Gilles.. `clipboard` feautre was not enabled in my vim, so i used your suggestion#2 and it works...

Comment: note: installing `gvim` gave me the clipboard feature

Comment: Of course, what `vi` (per the question) actually maps to is important.  VIM is as this answer.  NeoVIM, however, implements the `*` and `+` registers using the external utilities.  (See its `:help clipboard`.)