# Copy vim selected text to system clipboard

Tags: vim, xsel

My vim is not compiled with `clipboard` feature. So, i use `xsel` as suggested by [Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/214662/copy-current-line-to-clipboard-under-cursor-without-mouse-selection) to copy/paste the contents.

I use `:.w !xsel -b` for selecting the current line and, `:w !xsel -b` to select the entire document.

But sometimes, i need to move multiline selection done using `V` to clipboard. How can i do using `xsel`?

Note: i tried `Ctrl-Shift-c`, it didn't work. Anyways, i am not a great fan of Ctrl combo, since it breaks my fingers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still do basically the same thing from visual mode. Once you have the area selected, hit the following<sup>1</sup>:

```
:'>,'> !tee >(xsel -b)
```

You need to pipe to `tee` so that the contents of your selected area isn't cleared.

<sup>1</sup><sub>Adapted from [here](http://blog.bigsmoke.us/2010/01/31/xsel).</sub>

Comment: thanks a ton, turner.. it worked like charm... only thing is, when i am in visual mode and press `:`, it enters `:'<,'>` and  not `:'>,'>` as given here....

Comment: Whoops, let me correct that - you're right

Comment: no, turner... i changed the arrows direction  manually as per your answer to make it work... it says, the arrows indicate some ranging stuff.. not sure what it does... only the old answer of yours work...

Comment: Sorry - reset it to my original answer

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this is infuriatingly easy:  use the "v" command to highlight the text area you want.  Immediately press the "!" command, followed by your command.

So the sequence is "v"  "!"

Comment: Important notice: selected text will be replaced with output of the command you enter. If you use `xsel` without arguments then the text will be copied to clipboard and returned back, so the text in editor won't be changed. But `xsel -i` won't output the text back. Be careful.

Answer (score 2):

Type `:w !xsel -b` to copy the visual selection. When you press `:` while the visual selection is active, this inserts a range that designates the visual selection, so you'll end up executing `:'<,'>w !xsel -b`.

This copies all lines that are partially or completely selected, i.e. line where the selection starts and the line where the selection ends are fully included, even the parts that weren't selected. I don't know how to copy the selection exactly.

Of course, if Vim is compiled with the `+clipboard` option, just use `"+y`.

I've [looked for a way to make `"+` use `xsel` when Vim doesn't have clipboard support](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/332/define-custom-commands-for-the-and-registers), but I didn't get a fully working answer, this seems to be very difficult.