# can I copy some portion of a file into vim buffer (using yank) and paste it in windows app? (like into powerpoint) across vnc?

Tags: vnc, clipboard

Recently I'm doing an analysis on a big source files where frequently I copy a portion of the source file and paste it into windows PowerPoint.
For this I use mouse to select part of the source file text in vim (I use vnc on windows 10 to connect to my ubuntu machine) and paste it into PowerPoint. For this to be possible, I always enable clipboard exchange between vnc and my windows(using vncconfig).
The problem is when I want to copy-paste a very long portion. For this I have to use scroll-down and copy-paste more than once. But if I can use y(yank) to copy the text, and paste it into PowerPoint like I do it in vim, it will be very convenient ( I can mark a postion to 'a' and yank from 'a' to current location, using ":'a,.y"). Can I just paste the buffer that I yanked from vim directly to windows PowerPoint? (I don't want to paste the vim buffer into a file and use ftp to read it into PowerPoint, that's too cumbersome)

Comment: This is largely https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/214662/5132 again.

Comment: There's now a vim StackExchange https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's possible with WSL, but I don't believe it's doable via VNC